# Using textstream object to replace tab with spaces and delete characters

Tags: vba, excel, replace, filesystemobject

I have over a thousand .s2p files (a delimited text file used by electrical testing equipment) that were edited by a VBA macro, which opened each raw file in Excel as a tab-and-space delimited text file, and replaced a few of the columns with data columns from another file, then saved them in original format (.s2p) and closed them. This is the call I used to open the each file:

```
    Call Application.Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=(path & filename & ".s2p"), Origin:="437", DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Space:=True, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone)
```

Now, when I open the .s2p files in Notepad to view them, the original single space separating the columns is now a full tab, and some double quote (") characters were added to some of the file header lines (despite setting `TextQualifier` parameter to `xlTextQualifierNone`...)

Because of this I want to write another macro that can open all of these .s2p files again, loop through the lines, and replace any double quotes with blanks, and any tabs with single spaces. I was planning to use `.OpenAsTextStream` on each file, but it seems like the `TextStream` object doesn't support overwriting lines, but can only write new lines...

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do than just reading lines from the original file, and writing them to a newly created file? It is imperative that I save the final file as ".s2p" and not ".txt".

Comment: If the files aren't huge then you can read in the full content, do the replace, then overwrite the original file (or better - write the modified files to a subfolder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the text streams, just the basic input output actions available in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    FixFile "c:\temp\mytestfile.s2p"
End Sub

Sub FixFile(filename As String)
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim fileText As String
    Dim finalText As String

    fnum = FreeFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Open filename For Input As #fnum
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Critical error attempting to open " & filename & _
                    ". Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If

    finalText = ""
    Do Until EOF(fnum)
        Line Input #fnum, fileText
        fileText = Replace(fileText, """", " ", , , vbTextCompare)
        fileText = Replace(fileText, vbTab, " ", , , vbTextCompare)
        finalText = finalText & fileText & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close fnum

    fnum = FreeFile
    Open filename For Output As #fnum
    Print #fnum, finalText
    Close fnum

End Sub
```

> Edited to show line by line read with a final write.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a simpler approach than what I was going to do.

Comment: I have a followup question if you're willing to help further, since I'm new to the VBA I/O: after the `Replace` calls in your code above, what command would I use to edit just a single line, say the 3rd line, in each file?

Comment: See the edits above. To ONLY modify the third line (or any other condition), count the number of `Input`s and add an `If` statement.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I ended up figuring it out myself in a dirtier way by using `Seek #fnum, InStr()` and used `InStr` to search  the whole file text for a unique string that marked the beginning of the third line in order to get the first character position of the line. Then I used the `Write` command to write the new third line. Unfortunately, `Write` inserts double quotes around the written string, so then I had to run the routine to remove double quotes from the file again afterwards. It worked, but your method is much, much better. Thanks again!